# How to get rid of the window left behind after a HoloLens2 process is killed?

Tags: uwp, device, hololens

This is a question for HoloLens2.
After I kill an app (programmatically), frequently there is an empty window left behind. See attached picture.

Is there a way not to have this window or kill it too?
I am using "/api/taskmanager/app (DELETE)" from [Device portal API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/device-portal-api-reference).

Thanks,

Not to have a window left behind.

Answer (score 1):

This empty window contains the map and anchor data of the application. This is by design. HoloLens currently does not support deleting this data and closing this empty window while closing the application.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer.  I tried again with these steps:

(1) DELETE "api/taskmanager/app"+ my app,

(2) POST "api/holographic/mapmanager/resetmapandanchorsandsrdb".

The empty window is gone.  But I don't understand what the implication of "resetmapandanchorsandsrdb" is.  Any doc about this API?  

Is it harmful to the hololens2?

Sincerely,

Comment: I have edited the answer after the further discussion with my team. 
**1.** The UWP Device Portal and HoloLens Device Portal contain different functions, and Device Portal is only for development and not for production.
**2.** Killing a process/application through the API is not a common scenario in production environment, and such operations may cause crash.

Comment: **3.** Regarding the API **resetmapandanchorsandsrdb**, it does no harm to the device, but it will clear all the anchor and map data of the user shell interface, such as other windows’ position. It is not a common scenario. You may navigate to **[Device Portal] -> [System] -> [Map Manager]** and the button “**Rest System Map. Anchors & Spatial Mapping Database**” has the same functionality.

Comment: Appreciated, thanks

Comment: By design there is no way to get rid of it - say like if you don't want that stuff? Sounds more like lazyness to me.